# Button Selected State Android?

Tags: android, image, button

I am developing an application which consists of button.
Here Is My problem,how to set the selected state and unselected state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ox_mnu_dashboard_over" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ox_mnu_dashboard_normal"/>

</selector>
```

I am using this code but not working for me.
Here is the xml file:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDashboard"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/dashboard"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_dashboard"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set image when click on that imageButton like below code.

```
int isClicked =  0;
image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked1 == 0) {
                 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.second_image);
                isClicked1 = 1;
            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.original_image);
                isClicked1 = 0;
            }

        }
     });'
```

Comment: I need the selected state to be maintained

Comment: Then you need to set image when you click on that particular imageButton.